# Where can I post my question about developers changing their PC?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am a PHP developer, and I am using a desktop PC which I bought three years back. I do all my development work in this desktop PC.

A couple of days back, I bought a brand new PC with higher configuration, and I want to move all the required details from my old PC to new PC. I am not sure what are the details to be copied from my old PC to new PC.

I already moved bookmarks, FTP details, source code, the database from WAMP, and downloaded files. But I don't know if I am missing something.

Which Stack Exchange website can I post this question in?

Answer (score 3):

To start with it's kind of broad. Only you know what *you* need - and typically while there's a rough idea of what to move (like appdata and personal files); everyone's workflow is different. You'll know if you're missing something when you find you need it.

It's *roughly* within the scope of superuser.com *but* as is, it's unlikely the question would survive very long in its current form.

Comment: Thanks, Let me post an updated question in superuser.com